# не работает isset PHP

Tags: post, php

Суть в чем, есть форма на ней два поля, первое для выбора файла который нужно загрузить на сервер, второе указать ссылку на файл (расположение его на сервере), делаю две проверки полученых параметров, и выполняю определленные действия, дело в том что почему-то, первая проверка не хочет рабюотать...

вот код

```
<?php
//определяю дерриторию скрипта
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$uploaddir =str_replace('index.php','',$uploaddir);

?>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method=post>
<input type=file name="userfile" size=50><br>
<input type="text" name="userfile2" size="50" value="<? echo $uploaddir.'news.txt'; ?>"><br>
<input type=submit value="Поехали">
</form>

<?php
//Вывел форму с двома полями, первое для выбора фала с компа, второе чтобы указать иммя файла на сервере

//проверяю первое значение, указан ли файл на с компа, если да, загружаю его на сервер, и вывожу его адрес, прекращаю выполнение скриптиа
if (isset($_POST["userfile"])){
$temp=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $temp;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
echo $uploadfile.'<br>';
exit;
}

//проверяю второе значение, указан ли файл на с сервере, если да, загружаю его на сервер, и вывожу его адрес, прекращаю выполнение скриптиа
if (isset($_POST["userfile2"])){
$url = $_POST["userfile2"];
echo $url.'<br>';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
exit;
}
?>
```

первая проверка if (isset($_POST["userfile"])) не дает никакого результата, и все время выводит мне файл который уже есть на сервере...

где я допустил ошибку... зарание благодарен!

Comment: Проверять существование в этой папке файла с таким же именем, и удалять если существует, не пробовали?

Comment: каждый раз пробовал выбирать файл с уникальным именем, дело в том что не срабатывает именно проверка наличия параметра в пост запросе... тоесть если выбран файл он должен вывести его иммя, и прекратить дальнейшее выполнение скрипта

Comment: в пост запросе передается два параметра userfile и userfile2, если есть первый параметр выполнить одно действие если его нету проверить наличие второго параметра, выполнить действие второе, если нету параметров ничего не делать....

if (isset($_POST["userfile"])){
действие
exit;
}
if (isset($_POST["userfile2"])){
действие
exit;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST["userfile"]))// Вот это уже неверно. Во-первых, не isset, а !empty надо так как задано поле всегда если оно присутствует в форме, а во-вторых не $_POST, а сразу файлы смотрите.

$_FILES['userfile']['error']==0 && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало... долго я бы сам в этом разбирался!!!

Comment: просто +1 к карме тебе. я не стал писать, я иногда такие вопросы почему-то пропускаю, ибо на многие ответы уже даавно написаны :)